# How Create Get and Post Methods for the Login Page in wcf service in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am creating a WCF service in ASP.NET and there i need to implement Get and Post Methods for simple Login page

This is for running the application on Local host.I have SQL server for the database.

C#: 
This is the interface I have coded:

```
 [ServiceContract]
       public interface ILogin
        {
            [OperationContract(Name = "PostUserDetails")]
            [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",UriTemplate = "")]

            string UserName(Stream data);
            string UserPassword(Stream data);

            [OperationContract(Name = "GetUserDetails")]
            [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetUserDetails/inputStr/{name}")]
            string UserName(string name);
            string UserPassword(string name);
        }
```

This is the class I have coded:

```
public class Login :ILogin
    {
        public string UserName(Stream data)
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(data);
            string xmlString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            string returnValue = xmlString;

            return returnValue;
        }

        public string UserPassword(Stream data)
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(data);
            string xmlString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            string returnValue = xmlString;

            return returnValue;
        }

        public string UserName(string strUserName)
        {
            StringBuilder strReturnValue = new StringBuilder();
            // return username prefixed as shown below
            strReturnValue.Append(string.Format("You have entered userName as {0}", strUserName));
            return strReturnValue.ToString();
        }

        public string UserPassword(string strUserName)
        {
            StringBuilder strReturnValue = new StringBuilder();
            // return username prefixed as shown below
            strReturnValue.Append(string.Format("You have entered userName as {0}", strUserName));
            return strReturnValue.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I have also configured the web.config as:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyWCFService.Login" behaviourConfiguration ="loginbehaviour" >
        <endpoint name="webHttpBinding" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyWCFService.ILogin" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint name ="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyWCFServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"></serviceMetadata>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp"></behavior>
        <webHttp/>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I am getting  HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found Error

Comment: Someone pls help me

Comment: which method you try to access and get the HTTP error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cant use Stream as your input. because stream con not serialized. then you don't need to create two separate methods. create login like this and use * as your Method. something like this:

```
    [OperationContract(Name = "PostUserDetails")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "*",UriTemplate = "")]

    string UserName(Data data);
    string UserPassword(Data data);
```